# How to pass Primefaces Tab as UIComponent in bean method?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm trying to pass a Tab component to a bean method as UIComponent (for some permission issues that I'm developing), but I'm getting a instance of TabView instead of a Tab.

I'm using Tab as an example but I tried to call the same method in a p:outputLabel and I'm receiving a UIComponent PanelGrid instance.

Is it possible or should I need to pass the id too when it was as tab?

I'm running Primefaces 5.3.

```
<p:tabView id="myTabView">
    <p:tab id="tabOne" rendered="{myController.isUserHasView(component)}">
        ...
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>

//Bean Method
public boolean isUserHasView(UIComponent component) {
    System.out.println(component);
    return false;
}
```

I expect get Tab as UIComponent but I'm getting TabView with all their children.

Answer (score 0):

A [tab](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/tabview/Tab.java) is not a `UIComponent` ([does not have its own renderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component)) so the 'component' variable does not point to the tab but to its parent [tabview which is the real component and renders the tab](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/tabview/TabViewRenderer.java#L318). But even if it was possible, a new instance will be created every time the user opens the page, so checking via an 'instance' is not logical (unless you'd like to retrieve the id from the component). So since you should use something like an id anyway, using the id explicit is a good thing to do (and at least what I use).